# How to manage roles and users from API level securely

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an API for an angular app and we are using Identity Server 4 to write the token.  IDS4 is in a separate project and we have created some MVC views in that project for new users to register where we create then with UserManager in the controller.  The plan is we will eventually have several separate APIs for different projects but just 1 identity server managing them all.

The problem we have is that we need to be able to create users and modify their roles from the API projects.  As the API doesn't have access to IDS4 database where the identity tables are what is the best way to handle this?  Do I add endpoints to IDS4 project that give access to UserManager?  That seems a bit risky, if I do that how do I keep that secure so only the legit API project can use it and it doesn't open up a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - you can do that.

The API, that you want to use for user creation, should be a registered IDS client, that will authenticate based on the [client credentials flow](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) (clientId and clientSecret).

Then, I guess that you have an API that has access to the database. Then the new client API, will call the one with access to the database. The one with access, will be protected with IDS authorization.

Here of course you can add more security, for the specific actions, and allow them only for the new API (and not for every, authorized through IDS, call) using some custom attribute or authorization policy.

Comment: So the admin will be using the API verified as admin role by IDS4.  In the API call the token will be read as the Admin role but then in the code I want to make a call to the IDS4 endpoint with an ApiOnly roll or something or some way to communicate API to API.  Do I need to write code that gets the bearer token for the API and manually adds the headers or is there some better way to do this?  I am just trying to make it so admins dont have direct access to endpoints wrapping usermanager and roles but API can call them.

Comment: Well if you want to communicate API to API, without using the admin token - then yes, you somehow need to get the token for the calling API. Otherwise how are you going to authenticate the call?

Comment: OK, i guess i need to setup a OIDC client class to manage token as a singleton service then call it for user related functions.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Well I'm not fully aware of your whole case, but if you need just to get the access_token for the calling api, you can use a simple token client - `new TokenClient(<ids_tokenendpoint>, <ids_callingApiClientId>, <ids_CallingApiClientSecret)`.

Comment: Thanks that looks good.  The reason I need this is so that admin in the API can do things like suspend user or upgrade them by changing roles and stuff.